# Regular expressions [^a-z][0-9] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function checkEmail(str){
    var emailCheck = /[^a-z][0-9]/;
    if(emailCheck.test(str)){
      console.log("**Its Valid Mail");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Its not Valid");
    }
}
var x = '122a';
checkEmail(x);
```

I have been learning Regular Expressions.
From the above code what I understand, `x` should not contain small `a-z` and it must contain number, as you can see `122a` contains number as well as small letter `a`, I think it should be invalid but yet I get it as valid.
Can anyone please explain where I am thinking wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You regex `[^a-z][0-9]` matches 2 characters. The first would match not a-z using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and the second will match a digit. That will match `12` in `122a`

The method [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) searches for a match in a string, finds a match `12` and will return `true`.

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string to match 2 characters. In that case, `122a` will not match because that are 4 characters.

If you want to check if the string does not contain a lowercase character and does contain a digit you could use a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what followes is not `[a-z]` and that what follows is digit `[0-9]`.

[`^(?!.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/qx14DZ/1)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, you are not checking the start and end of the string.

Specify the ***Start*** and ***End*** of your Regex:

```
/^[^a-z][0-9]+$/
```

The caret `^` and dollar `$` characters have special meaning in a regexp. They are called **anchors**.
The caret `^` matches at the beginning of the text, and the dollar `$` – in the end.

```js
function checkEmail(str){
  var emailCheck = /^[^a-z][0-9]+$/;
  if(emailCheck.test(str)){
    console.log("**Its Valid Mail");
  }
  else{
    console.log("Its not Valid");
  }
}
var x = '122a';
checkEmail(x);
```

**For more**: [Start of String and End of String Anchors in Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try `/^[0-9]+$/g.test(str)`.

```
> var s = '122a'
undefined
>
> /^[0-9]+$/g.test(s)
false
>
> var s = '122'
undefined
>
> /^[0-9]+$/g.test(s)
true
>
```